# I need that the last 3 searches are saved in a cookie and displayed

Tags: php, search, cookies, session-cookies, cookie-session

I want the last 3 searches to be saved in a Cookie and displayed in a '< p>' tag.
Here is my HTML code:

```
    <form class="Dform" method="POST" action="index.php">
           <input type="text" name="search" value="">
           <input type="submit" name="" value="Search">
    </form>
```

I only managed to display the previous search but I don't know how to do the 2 previous ones, here is my php code:

```
<?php
  if (!empty($_POST['search']))
    {
      setcookie('PreviousSearch', $_POST['search'], time()+60*60,'',localhost);
    }
?>

<?php
    $r1 = htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['PreviousSearch']);
    echo '<p> Previous search (1) : '.$r1.'</p>'; 
?>
```

Comment: Have a look at serialize. I think, it'll help you

Comment: I looked at serialize but I don't see how it can help solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.
While I'd prefer the database approach, I'll keep it simple and show you the serialize approach.

What you currently have in your Cookie: the last search.
What you want in your Cookie: the last three searches.

So, we need an array in the Cookie. But we can't put a plain array inside. There are a few workarounds for this. I'll use the `serialize` approach. But we could also work with json, comma separated lists, ...

Your code should do something like this:

```php
// Gets the content of the cookie or sets an empty array
if (isset($_COOKIE['PreviousSearch'])) {
    // as we serialize the array for the cookie data, we need to unserialize it
    $previousSearches = unserialize($_COOKIE['PreviousSearch']);
} else {
    $previousSearches = array();
}

$previousSearches[] = $_POST['search'];
if (count($previousSearches) > 3) {
    array_shift($previousSearches);
}
/*
 * alternative: prepend the searches
$count = array_unshift($previousSearches, $_POST['search']);
if ($count > 3) {
    array_pop($previousSearches);
}
 */

// We need to serialize the array if we want to pass it to the cookie
setcookie('PreviousSearch', serialize($previousSearches), time()+60*60,'',localhost);
```

My code is untested, as I didn't work with cookie for ages. But it should work.